# Principal Components of PCA

Tags: machine-learning, pca, data-visualization, dimensionality-reduction, anomaly-detection

I have a dataset combined with normals samples and fault samples. We use PCA on normal samples and faults samples separately. I observe that the last PCs help us to have better separation than for example the third PC. What could be the reasons as we say first PCs hold more data. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

PCA is an unsupervised technique of structuring your data. PCA focuses on finding principle components which exhibit the largest amount of variation given a certain dataset (Think about looking at the data from an angle where the horizontal spread of the data points is the largest, by that we hope that we are better able to distinguish between different data points and there potential outcomes). However, this variation can be induces by noise and not by causal relation to your response variable. Hence, the first component might account for 60% of the variation in your dataset but main parts of this component are driven by noise which does not help your prediction at all. The last PC in your case might exhibit just less variation but with respect to the target variable a more important variation. If you want to ensure components that are related to the response variable I would suggest you try partial least squares as an (supervised) alternative.

Comment: "Structuring your data" is kinda wrong but I assume you know the purpose of PCA if you are applying it.